# Transform a "collection" (list, set, single object, ...) into a new collection of the same type in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, I use the terms "container" and "collection" in a very general way, not linked to any Python terminology.

I have the following function in Python. It takes a list of ids `idlist` and returns a list of objects from `objs` corresponding to those ids. That works fine:

```
def findObj(idlist, objs):
    return [next(o for o in objs if id == o.id) for id in idlist]
```

The problem is: `idlist` and the return value should not necessarily need to be a Python `list`. I would wish that `idlist` could also be one plain id, and the function would return a single object. Or `idlist` would be a Python `set` and the function would return a `set` of objects.

**How can I achieve that I can use various "container" types (including a plain id) for `idlist` and get returned the same "container" type?**

Comment: What about 
return type(idlist)([next(o for o in objs if id == o.id) for id in idlist]) ?

Comment: `type(idlist)` will give you type of object passed to function. Now you have to call that type constructor [`t = type(idlist); t(input_arguments)`] and figure out all corner cases (like not sequence, but object etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I argue that what you have in mind is **not** a good API.
It's simpler, more robust and less error prone to have the function return a specific type and let the user handle the eventual conversion.

In particular I'd prefer making the function lazy using a generator:

```
def find_obj(ids, objs):
    try:
        for id in ids:
            yield next(o for o in objs if o.id == id)
    except TypeError:
        # ids not iterable? assume it is a plain id
        yield next(o for o in objs if o.id == ids)
```

Now a user can just do:

```
list(find_obj(...))
set(find_obj(...))
next(find_obj(...))   # 1 element
```

And obtain the thing he wants.

Added benefits:

- *Explicit is better than implicit*: here the type conversion is explicit. Image code where the calls are of the kind `find_obj(some_var_defined_elsewhere, objects)` now how do you know which type will be returned if the definition of the input is not near there?
- you can pass a type `X` as input and convert to type `Y` without wasting intermediate space and doing an unneccessary conversion
- No special cases needed. The caller can provide an input that doesn't follow the usual way to construct containers (note that there is no standard way to build a container)

---

Alternative that special cases the single id case:

```
def find_obj(ids, objs):
    try:
        return (next(o for o in objs if o.id == id) for id in ids)
    except TypeError:
        for o in objs:
            if o.id == id:
                return o
```

The above returns a generator when given a sequence of `ids` and returns a plain object (instead of a 1-element-generator) when passed in a single `id`.

---

Finally: *most of the time* (but **not** always) sequences have a constructor that accepts an iterable and builds the container with those elements. This means that:

```
type(some_iterable)(something for el in some_iterable)
```

will produce a container of the same type as `some_iterable`.

Note that some classes require a `list` instead of a generic iterable so you'd have to use `type(some_iterable)([<as-before>])` and other containers do *not* have such a constructor. In this last case only the caller could perform the conversion. The first solution handles this nicely without any special case.

You could generalize more the function by adding a parameter to perform the conversion:

```
def find_obj(ids, objs, converter=None):
    if converter is None:
        converter = type(ids)

    try:
        return converter(next(o for o in objs if o.id == id) for id in ids)
    except TypeError:
        return next(o for o in objs if o.id == ids)
```

in this way the caller can customize the conversion if he's dealing with strange types.

---

An added note: in python we use "duck typing", i.e. just use the object as if it was of the correct type and if it raises an exception fallback to do other stuff. In some cases it's simpler to first check for support of certain operations, in that cases you could use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#isinstance) with the abstract base classes found in [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html) to see if an object is [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable), a [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence), a [`Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to:

```
import collections



def findObj(idlist, objs):
   if isinstance(idlist, collections.Iterable):
       return type(idlist)([next(o for o in objs if id == o.id) for id in idlist])
   else:
       #cover case when idlist is just plain object
       pass
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if your plain object's id is passed (for idliist) as int (not string)

```
def findObj(idlist, objs):
    t = type(idlist)
    try:
        iter(idlist)
        return t([next(o for o in objs if id == o.id) for id in idlist])
    except TypeError, te: #not iterator.  So single id and object
        return idlist if idlist == objs.id else False
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to use exceptions for something that is not actually an "exception"? Don't know what the Python community thinks about that.